# before_create in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model `User` that has `name`, `email` and `hash` fields.

I save data to this by doing:

```
@u = User.create(:name=>'test', :email=>"test@mail.com")
@u.save
```

How can I incorporate the `before_create` callback so that before saving the record the hash value gets a hash string by following code:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('something secret' + email)
```

How will my `User` model look like?

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_hash

   def set_hash 
      //what goes in here?
   end
end
```

Comment: Incidentally, User.create saves the user, so @u.save is unnecessary.  If you want to do something between making a new model and saving, use User.new with the same parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access (and alter) instance variables of your current model using the self keyword.

```
def set_hash
  self.email = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('something secret' + self.email)
end
```