# Rails best way (or best practices)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which I don't know how to focus the following issue:

I have been reading the following posts

- [before_create in rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393143/before-create-in-rails-model)
- [before_create in user model -- set integer based on email (RAILS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227202/before-create-in-user-model-set-integer-based-on-email-rails)
- [Access current_user in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513383/access-current-user-in-model)

I have a project where I want to manage some properties (Assets). 
I have Property, Owner, Company and Users.

The House and the Owner are linked in the DB with a FK so 1 Company has N Owners and 1 Company has N Properties.

The model User is linked to Company, so 1 Company has N users.

How can I access the `company_id` in the model Users in order to store this ID in the Properties and in the Owner model when the Property and Owner is created?

Do I have to do it in the controller and model?

Owner Class

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord

  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :property_owners
  has_many :properties, :through => :property_owners

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :country

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties
```

Property Class

```
 class Property < ApplicationRecord

   acts_as_paranoid

   has_many :property_owners   has_many :owners, :through =>
 :property_owners

   belongs_to :company   belongs_to :country
```

This is the Company

```
Class Company < ApplicationRecord    
    has_many :properties   
      has_many :owners
```

And the last one is Users

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_create :set_default_role, only: :create

  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user_role

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

Comment: If company has many users, houses and owners, these three all should have a company_id field. So where is the problem, I don't understand

Comment: Yes, all of them they have company_id, I wan to store the company_id in House and Owner where is associated in the User. When the user creates the New House or the New Owner I wan to add this id (company_id)

Comment: I would say its very unclear what you are asking and you just seem to be generally confused and not have a clear domain model either. What you are looking for is most likely `has_one through:` and `has_many through:` associations. If you can actually include a your models and a bit about the actual problem domain you are trying to solve (is it for example a real estate app or what are you trying to build?) then this question might be answerable. Right now it will most likely get buried or closed.

Comment: I added the classes

Comment: using `before_create` in a model isn't the right approach. That's a method specifically written for controller callbacks. Models have their own system of callbacks (see [activerecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)). As for accessing `current_user` in the model, the best way is to pass it as an argument to method calls.

Comment: maxple I read this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have your associations right, in your controller, when a user creates, for example, a house entry:

```
def create
     @property = current_user.company.properties.new(property_params)
     ....
 end
```

Where `current_user` can be replaced by the variable containing the user currently logged on and `property_params` are the strong params, sent to the controller from your form.

Likewise for `owner`

Comment: I am receiving undefined method `properties' for nil:NilClass, the current_user I assume that is comming from devise as default value, if I raw current_user.company_id in the view I see the value that is storaged in the User model

Comment: Is there a company for the user?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This message means that current user has no company (company is nil). According to your model, there should be "@user.company" or "current_user.company", since user "belongs to :company"...